# Gtk+3 Grid Blocking Background Image In Overlay

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, gtk3

I've been trying to get into GUI programming with Python on Xubuntu 14.04 by following a few guides like this one [here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout.html). I wanted to have a background image in my GUI with whatever buttons on top of it. [I searched on stackoverflow and came across a person having a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232952/gtk3-image-full-window-image-from-file-python3). His solution worked, but the grid filled up the entire window and I can no longer see the background image. How do I fix this? Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-:


from gi.repository import Gtk #Here we are importing the GTK3 library to use in our program

class mywindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        #In the class's constructor, we have to call the constructor of the super class. In addition, we tell it to set
        #the value of the property title to Media Manager v1.0
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Media Manager v1.0") #Creates an Empty Window

        #use an overlay for the background image
        self.overlay = Gtk.Overlay()
        self.add(self.overlay)
        self.background = Gtk.Image.new_from_file('Background.jpg')
        self.overlay.add(self.background)

        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Hello")
        self.button1.connect("clicked", self.on_button1_clicked)
        self.grid.add(self.button1)
        self.overlay.add_overlay(self.grid)



        #Gtk.Window.set_default_size(self, 400,325)
        Gtk.Window.set_position(self, Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)




    def on_button1_clicked(self, button):
        print "Hello"


    def on_button2_clicked(self, button):
        print "Exiting..."




def main():
    window = mywindow()

    #connect to the window's delete event to ensure that the application is terminated if we click on the x to close the window
    window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit) 

    #Display the window
    window.show_all()

    #Finally, start the GTK+ processing loop which we quit when the winndow is closed.
    Gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass values for the `valign` and `halign` properties when creating the grid and/or the button. The default for these properties is `Gtk.Align.FILL` which causes them to cover all the space given to them. Instead, pick `Gtk.Align.START`, `Gtk.Align.END`, or `Gtk.Align.CENTER`.